# Where is the "Generate automatic URL alias" setting stored?

Tags: uri

I have about a 100 nodes where I need to manually change the url alias in the url_alias table. I want to make sure the "Generate automatic URL alias" setting is disabled for those nodes so the url doesn't change when a user changes the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was under the impression the "Generate automatic URL alias" setting would be saved in the database for each node. That's not the case.

Instead I just had to change the pathauto setting from "Create a new alias. Delete the old alias."   to "Do nothing. Leave the old alias intact."  ([credits](http://drupal.org/node/1443372))

Comment: But this doesn't answer your original question. I still want to know where the the “Generate automatic URL alias” setting is stored. I want to bulk updates 1000's of nodes to check this box.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply do not want them to change, then put this in your pattern for that specific content type:

```
[current-page:url:path]
```

**Disclaimer**: You probably want to test this once before updating all of them