# Pathauto bulk update for taxonomy terms with unchecked “Generate automatic URL alias”

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have the same issue addressed for D7 here:
[Bulk Generating URL aliases for taxonomy terms doesn't do anything](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256560/bulk-generating-url-aliases-for-taxonomy-terms-doesnt-do-anything)
or here:
[Bulk update for unchecked "Generate automatic URL alias"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41628/bulk-update-for-unchecked-generate-automatic-url-alias)

And I'm looking for a corresponding workaround for D8, querying the DB directly.

For D7 seems that the following solution works:

```
UPDATE pathauto_state SET pathauto="1" WHERE entity_type="taxonomy_term";
```

I did some research for D8:

1. cannot find any "pathauto_state" table within a D8 database
2. so I tried to find how and where the “Generate automatic URL alias”
   is stored but
       without success (see also for this:
       [Where is the "Generate automatic URL alias" setting stored?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33596/where-is-the-generate-automatic-url-alias-setting-stored))

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no simple SQL query to update "Generate automatic URL alias" status for nodes and terms for Drupal 8.

Data contained in table `key_value` but I don't think it's possible to use it directly.